# Unity - Character Fbx Size is Increased in Build

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, fbx

I have a character fbx with the original size of `273kb`. In the android build `character` size becomes `3.3mb`.

[image]

**Note!**

I tried importing character in empty project without any texture and animations but the problem still remains.

[image]

**Any idea?**
why this happening and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This method work for me**

- Select the `character`
- from the `inspector window` click on `model`
- Turn off `Import BlendShapes` from options.

[image: solution]

Comment: Hello, what if I need those blendshapes. What should I do?