# unity fbx model size becomes larger after build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a 3d female fbx model, which has the size of 56mb. After building an apk, the model's size has grown to 1.1gb. This caused my app to crash on launched due to out of memory.

What happened to the model? What tools can be used to analyze its size component and reduce its size? I tried putting only this model in a new project without any textures and the model still takes up 1.1gb.

I have googled but rarely found some solutions. I saw [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76012876/unity-character-fbx-size-is-increased-in-build) saying that unchecking Import BlendShapes in the inspector would be helpful. But I do need blend shapes to allow my users to customize the face of my model.

I also have tried packing it into an asset bundle, but it still has the size of 600mb, which is still very large.

[image]
[image]